# RTSP camera sub stream url

Tags: python, camera, rtsp, onvif, python-onvif

I want to fetch `rtsp` path of secondary stream of any given camera. The camera models are different, so are the manufacturers.

I tried using `ONVIF` for this, but it gives me `rtsp` path of primary stream only. I need something to get secondary stream.

Is there any possible way of achieving this? Any `python` library which can help or anything else?